# how to integrate a monolithic jhipster application with another jhispter application. ?- Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I have made three different applications in j JHipster with monolithic. I need to merge these applications. I know that by using micro-services my quest can be easy but the current requirement is to do the merging with the monolithic pattern only.
I need to merge two applications with another or main application. I am using MySQL as database. I don't know where I need to change and how. Please help me out, I am a newbie in this scenario.

i tried to create a java file for setter getter methods and and a dao file for three databases and now in the main class file and am trying to take every dao file as an array of object and integrate it and put it into the third db.is it possible.i wanted to show the code bt,since i am new not able to maintain the coding standards to show.

by this i way i tried to  involve three databases in a single scenario and want to complete my query through CRUD model.

Comment: i need to make a spring project with a java class in which i can integrate the two database in insert it down into the third database.i want to keep them separated.yes ,i want to keep 3 databases.my version of jhispster is the current release 3.12.2.here i am editing my question

Answer (score 0):

as you already pointed out, the proper way of merging here would be using the microservice option, which you cannot take, as you are forced to use monolithic architecture...

### almost automatic merge

if you did *not* changed anything to your code, after generating the entities, you just can put the contents of your applications .jhipster directory into one, and run `yo jhipster --with-entities` to regenerate the entities in one application. You should keep in mind, you will have to take a look at your main/resource/config/liquibase folder, to set the migration ids properly.

### manual merge

For this you should be more experienced in the underlying technologies, as you will have to:

- recreate your entity classes
- recreate zour DAO/Repositories
- (maybe) recreate your services, or service implementations
- recreate your REST controllers
- do a proper liquibase migration
- provide some tests
- migrate the frontend code, by adding states, components, templates etc..

the most of these things you just can copy paste already generated code.

For more information, you should ask more precise, what is not working, if you already tried something...

Comment: Thank you David .This is working.i did the same as u said above and my code in the spring mvc which i wanted to develop is successful.i mapped the entities ,merged them and inserted into the main database with the required entities.all i need now is to link the java code with my monolithic application.and yeah frontend part is yet to be modified.looking forward.